# Using R to simulate a biased 6 sided dice

Tags: r

In R I want to figure the code to simulate a biased 6 sided die being thrown 44 times.
The die is biased in the sense that the number 6 is twice as likely to be thrown
as any other individual number.

I can do this for an unbiased dice but not sure what to do for this one.

Thanks

Comment: See the `prob` argument of sample. Using `prob=c (1,1,1,1,1,2)` should give you what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need both the `replace=TRUE` and the `prob`-argument set to the non-equal probability setting of your choice.

```
throws <- sample(1:6, 44, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1,1,1,1,1,2)/7 )
# Two realizations
> throws <- sample(1:6, 44, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1,1,1,1,1,2)/7 )
> table(throws)
throws
 1  2  3  4  5  6 
10  5  8  7  3 11 
> throws <- sample(1:6, 44, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1,1,1,1,1,2)/7 )
> table(throws)
throws
 1  2  3  4  5  6 
 7  3  4  8  7 15
```

Notice that the outcome is still (pseudo)-random and that it's still possible to have departures from what the naive student of probability might expect. And I cannot resist the pedantic correction that this is for a single die rather than "dice", which is plural.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome responses to the problem. I understand the workings mostly but wondered why the /7 in the process?

Comment: It's not actually needed. I put it in so the probabilities would sum to 1 but the default behavior is to do that anyway (as demonstrated by Telford's answer which runs without complaint..

Answer (score 0):

```
sample(1:6, size = 44, replace = TRUE, prob = c(rep(1, 5), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sample and specify probabilities for each number.

```
  sample(x = 1:6, size = 44, replace = T, prob = c(rep(1/7, 5), 2/7))
```